# xargs: String concatenation

Tags: grep, xargs

```bash
zgrep -i XXX XXX | grep -o "RID=[0-9|A-Z]*" |
   uniq | cut -d "=" -f2 |
   xargs -0 -I string echo "RequestID="string
```

My output is

```
RequestID=121212112
8127127128
8129129812
```

But my requirement is to have the request ID prefixed before all the output.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Since I am new to this ,, I am not aware of the formalities .. Thank you for telling this and I will surely accept the answer

Comment: I was googling about how to concatenate with xargs, and the answer is: use `-I`. `man xargs`: *`-I replace-str`* *Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input. Implies -x and -L 1.* Please note that `-L 1` should suffice, so `-n 1` is useless. The `-0` is the problem here.

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar task and this worked for me. It might be what you are looking for:
`zgrep -i XXX XXX | grep -o "RID=[0-9|A-Z]*" |
   uniq | cut -d "=" -f2 |
   xargs -I {} echo "RequestID="{}`

Comment: yes! **best answer**, `cat myEpochDates | xargs -I {} date -d @{}`  generates ISO dates. Example `date -d @1234567890`

Answer (score 15):

Try `-n` option of `xargs`.

> -n max-args

> Use at most max-args arguments per command line.  Fewer than max-args arguments will be used if the size (see the -s  option)
> is  exceeded,
> unless the -x option is given, in which case xargs will exit.

Example:

```bash
$ echo -e '1\n2' | xargs echo 'str ='
str = 1 2

$ echo -e '1\n2' | xargs -n 1 echo 'str ='
str = 1
str = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments ... Now my problem is this xargs -L 1 -I string echo "RequestId="string|xargs -L 1 -I string zcat XXXX.gz|agrep -dEOE string ... Now the xargs string has to pipe through the next one which is agrep would take .. But I am not getting the desired output.. Any ideas about this .. Thank you ...

Comment: @User I'm not sure I understand. You need to show the example input and desired output the same way you did in this question. Maybe start a new question?

Comment: **bad answer**, non-complete.  See about `xargs -n 1 date -d @`? not work. for example to concatenate as `date -d @1234567890`